# AWS CodeBuild issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, build, devops

I've followed the official guide by AWS in order to build and test my android app using CodePipeline but the build log tells:

```
[Container] 2020/02/04 17:25:04 Running command mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.125 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-04T17:25:09Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory 
(/codebuild/output/src849781127/src). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> 
[Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following 
articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException

[Container] 2020/02/04 17:25:09 Command did not exit successfully mvn install exit status 1
[Container] 2020/02/04 17:25:09 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2020/02/04 17:25:09 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error 
while executing command: mvn install. Reason: exit status 1
[Container] 2020/02/04 17:25:09 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2020/02/04 17:25:09 Running command echo Build completed on `date`
Build completed on Tue Feb 4 17:25:09 UTC 2020

[Container] 2020/02/04 17:25:09 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2020/02/04 17:25:09 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2020/02/04 17:25:09 Expanding base directory path: .
[Container] 2020/02/04 17:25:09 Assembling file list
[Container] 2020/02/04 17:25:09 Expanding .
[Container] 2020/02/04 17:25:09 Expanding file paths for base directory .
[Container] 2020/02/04 17:25:09 Assembling file list
[Container] 2020/02/04 17:25:09 Expanding target/messageUtil-1.0.jar
[Container] 2020/02/04 17:25:09 Skipping invalid file path target/messageUtil-1.0.jar
[Container] 2020/02/04 17:25:09 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: FAILED
[Container] 2020/02/04 17:25:09 Phase context status code: CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching artifact 
paths found
```

I'm new to AWS and I used the following buildspec.yml I found in the official documentation:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto11
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Nothing to do in the pre_build phase...
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - mvn install
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - target/messageUtil-1.0.jar
```

Can anyone help me?

Regards,
Antonio

Comment: I don't know much about Java, but it looks like your POM file is not present in the current directory when you execute "mvn install". Are you using Maven? If so, is there a POM file in your directory? If you don't know the answer to these questions, just add a line to your buildspec under "commands:" `- ls -la` right before the mvn install.

Comment: You was right, thank you very much. I've created my pom.xml file but I don't know hot to write the last line for my own project; it should be something like this:

artifacts:
  files:
    - target/messageUtil-1.0.jar

but the build console tells:

 Skipping invalid file path target/messageUtil-1.0.jar
Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: FAILED
 Phase context status code: CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching artifact paths found

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to put my comments in an answer. It looks like your POM file was not present in the current directory when you executed "mvn install". If you're using Maven there needs to be a POM file in your current directory. As for the `Skipping invalid file path target/messageUtil-1.0.jar Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: FAILED Phase context status code: CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching artifact paths found` error you can change the following in the `buildspec` file:

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

It will grab everything including your JAR file.